# How can I number each element in my list for a given range n?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, range

I am trying to number elements in my nested list for a given range for the given function:

```
numbered_elements(list, n)
```

Use the following list as example:

```
fruits = [ ['GRAPE', 'APPLE'], ['ORANGE'], ['BANANA', 'PEAR'] ]
```

And,

```
n = 3
```

I want a function that will take as input the list `fruits` and `n=3` and outputs the following:

```
[ ['GRAPE0', 'GRAPE1', 'GRAPE2', 'APPLE0', 'APPLE1', 'APPLE2'], ['ORANGE0', 'ORANGE1', 'ORANGE2'], ['BANANA0', 'BANANA1', 'BANANA2', 'PEAR0', 'PEAR1', 'PEAR2'] ]
```

Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
empty = []
for l in fruits:
    for element in l:
        for a in range(n):
            empty.append(element + str(a))
return empty
```

This function is returning:

```
  ['GRAPE0', 'GRAPE1', 'GRAPE2', 'APPLE0', 'APPLE1', 'APPLE2', 'ORANGE0', 'ORANGE1', 'ORANGE2', 'BANANA0', 'BANANA1', 'BANANA2', 'PEAR0', 'PEAR1', 'PEAR2']
```

So what I'm trying to figure out is how to still keep it as a nested list.

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: You're right. I have attached the code I have thus far. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nested list: you need to handle your appending in a loop as well, clearing the accretion list for each new outer-level list.

```
fruits = [ ['GRAPE', 'APPLE'], ['ORANGE'], ['BANANA', 'PEAR'] ]
n = 3

roster = []    # Clear the final output list only once
for l in fruits:
    empty = []          # Clear the suffix list for each new sub-list of fruit
    for element in l:
        for a in range(n):
            empty.append(element + str(a))
    roster.append(empty)

print(roster)
```

Output (line feeds inserted for readability):

```
[['GRAPE0', 'GRAPE1', 'GRAPE2', 'APPLE0', 'APPLE1', 'APPLE2'],
 ['ORANGE0', 'ORANGE1', 'ORANGE2'],
 ['BANANA0', 'BANANA1', 'BANANA2', 'PEAR0', 'PEAR1', 'PEAR2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple iteration over list of lists and repeating each element `'n'` times:

```
def numbered_elements(lst, n):
    return [[f'{y}{i}' for y in x for i in range(n)] for x in lst]
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> fruits = [['GRAPE', 'APPLE'], ['ORANGE'], ['BANANA', 'PEAR']]
>>> numbered_elements(fruits, 3)
[['GRAPE0', 'GRAPE1', 'GRAPE2', 'APPLE0', 'APPLE1', 'APPLE2'], ['ORANGE0', 'ORANGE1', 'ORANGE2'], ['BANANA0', 'BANANA1', 'BANANA2', 'PEAR0', 'PEAR1', 'PEAR2']]
```